# LWUIT menuBar refreshTheme not working?

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-form

I'd like to dynamically change the text of a Command depending on some state, so normally I went to Google and LWUIT blogs said that using `refreshTheme()` on `MenuBar` should do the trick.
So I used the following code, but it sadly didn't work

```
if (isPlaying) {
          playButton.setCommandName("Pause");
}else{
          playButton.setCommandName("Play");
}
this.getMenuBar().refreshTheme();
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Or did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't refresh. The text of the button is set when the command is placed so you can't do that.

You will need to use `removeCommand(cmd)` followed by `addCommand(newCmd)`.

Furthermore, `refreshTheme()` has absolutely nothing to do with anything.

Comment: So I should just removeCommand then setCommandName and then addCommand again to the same form?
Without the need to refreshTheme on form or menuBar or anything?

Comment: Yes, that should work. A repaint might be necessary. Its been years, we are just busy with Codename One and I don't remember which issues were changed when.